# Siri Shortcuts: How to require unlocking the phone

Tags: ios, siri, sirishortcuts, intents-extension

Siri Intent: Is it possible to require that the user to unlock the iPhone before the execution take place? I don't want the Intent to cause the corresponding iOS app to be launched.

If I uncheck the "Supports background execution" box (shown below), Siri requires the devices to be unlocked but it also launches the app and I don't want that.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer. See the screenshot. In the Intent definition file, set the "authentication" to "Restricted While Locked"

[image]